# Problema com Classes e Pacotes no python

Tags: python, tkinter

Fiz uma pergunta mas resolvi melhora-la para ter um melhor entendimento,e também porque ninguém conseguiu responder pelo fato de pouca explicação nessa aqui estarei falando dos pacotes ou seja para cada bloco e um arquivo com nome diferente então se colocar tudo dentro de um só não vai funcionar. Bom estou com um problema na hora de chamar um atributo em um outro arquivo, ou seja eu estou trabalhando com pacotes o primeiro pacote(arquivos diferentes) é o principal com nome de Gerenciador.py e nele tem esse código:

```
from Tkinter import *
from constantes import *
from BD import *

class main():
  def __init__(self, principal):

    self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame1.pack()
    self.BCriar = Button(self.frame1, width = 10, command = self.criar, text = 'Criar')
    self.BCriar.pack(side = LEFT, pady = '10px')
    self.BGerenciar = Button(self.frame1, width = 10, command = self.gerenciar, text = 'Gerenciar')
    self.BGerenciar.pack(side = LEFT, pady = '10px')
    self.BDeletar = Button(self.frame1, width = 10, command = self.deletar, text = 'Deletar')
    self.BDeletar.pack(side = LEFT, pady = '10px')
    self.BAjuda = Button(self.frame1, width = 10, command = self.ajuda, text = 'Ajuda')
    self.BAjuda.pack(side = LEFT, pady = '10px')
    self.BSobre = Button(self.frame1, width = 10, command = self.sobre, text = 'Sobre')
    self.BSobre.pack(side = LEFT, pady = '10px')

  def criar(self):

   self.BCriar.pack_forget()
   self.BGerenciar.pack_forget()
   self.BDeletar.pack_forget()
   self.BAjuda.pack_forget()
   self.BSobre.pack_forget()
   criarBanco()

  def gerenciar(self):
    pass
  def deletar(self):
    pass
  def ajuda(self):
    pass
  def sobre(self):
    pass

 principal = Tk()
 main(principal
 principal.geometry('800x600')
 principal.resizable(False, False)
 principal.title('Gerenciador De Cadastro')
 principal.mainloop()
```

Quando clicar no botao criar ele entra na proxima página, que no caso é esse codigo com nome de BD.py(outro arquivo):

```
from Tkinter import *
from sqlite3 import *
from constantes import *
from Criacao import *
class criarBanco(object):
  def __init__(self, principal):
#frames e empacotamento de frames
    self.font = ('Arial', '14', 'bold')
    self.font1 = ('Arial', '10', 'bold')
    self.frame0 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame0.pack(pady = padyFrame0)
    self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame1.place()
    self.frame1.pack()
    self.frame1['bg'] = bgFrame1
    self.frame5 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame5.pack(pady = padyFrame0)
    self.frame2 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame2.place()
    self.frame2.pack()
    self.frame2['bg'] = bgFrame2
    self.frameBotEnviar = Frame(principal)
    self.frameBotEnviar.place()
    self.frameBotEnviar.pack(pady = padyBotEnviar)
##Texto de Aviso de Marcado Ou no
    self.nomeMarcado = Label(self.frame5, text = 'Nome = No ', font = self.font1)
    self.nomeMarcado.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.corMarcado = Label(self.frame5, text = ' Cor = No ', font = self.font1)
    self.corMarcado.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.cpfMarcado = Label(self.frame5, text = ' CPF = No  ', font = self.font1)
    self.cpfMarcado.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.emailMarcado = Label(self.frame5, text = ' Email = No', font = self.font1)
    self.emailMarcado.pack(side = LEFT)


#Variaveis CheckButton
    self.Vnome = IntVar()
    self.Vcor = IntVar()
    self.Vcpf = IntVar()
    self.Vemail = IntVar()

#################

    self.L1 = Label(self.frame1, font = self.font, text = "  Nome do Seu Banco de Dados  ", bg = bgNomeDoBanco)       
    self.L1.pack()
    self.LL1 = Label(self.frame1, bg = '#B5B5B5')
    self.LL1.pack()
    self.E1 = Entry(self.frame1, bd = 5, highlightcolor = '#1E90FF')
    self.E1.pack()          
    self.L2 = Label(self.frame1, font = self.font, text = ' Digite a Senha do seu Banco de Dados ', bg = bgNomeDoBanco)
    self.L2.pack()
    self.E2 = Entry(self.frame1, show = '*',  bd = 5, highlightcolor = '#1E90FF')
    self.E2.pack() 
    self.L3 = Label(self.frame1, font = self.font, text = ' Confirme a Senha do seu Banco de Dados ', bg = bgNomeDoBanco)
    self.L3.pack()
    self.E3 = Entry(self.frame1, show = '*', bd = 5, highlightcolor = '#1E90FF')
    self.E3.pack()


## CheckButtons

    self.nome = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bg = bgCheckButton, font = self.font1, command = self.PegarValor, bd = 3, text = 'Nome', onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = self.Vnome)
    self.nome.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.cor = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bg = bgCheckButton,  font = self.font1, command = self.PegarValor, bd = 3, text = 'Cor', onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = self.Vcor)
    self.cor.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.cpf = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bg = bgCheckButton,  font = self.font1, command = self.PegarValor, bd = 3, text = 'CPF', onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = self.Vcpf)
    self.cpf.pack(side = LEFT)   
    self.email = Checkbutton(self.frame2, bg = bgCheckButton,  font = self.font1, command = self.PegarValor, bd = 3, text = 'Email', onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable = self.Vemail)
    self.email.pack(side = LEFT)
    self.BotEnviar = Button(self.frameBotEnviar, command = self.enviaBanco, bg = '#CFCFCF',  text = 'Enviar', font = self.font1, bd = 5)
    self.BotEnviar.pack()

#################
  def PegarValor(self): 
   v = [0,0,0,0]

   if self.Vnome.get() == 1:
    v[0] = 1
    self.nomeMarcado['text'] = 'Nome = Sim  '
   else: 
    self.nomeMarcado['text'] = ' Nome = No  '
   if self.Vcor.get() == 1:
      v[1] = 1
      self.corMarcado['text'] = ' Cor = Sim  '
   else:
    self.corMarcado['text'] = ' Cor = No  '
   if self.Vcpf.get() == 1:
      v[2] = 1
      self.cpfMarcado['text'] = ' CPF = Sim  '
   else:
      self.cpfMarcado['text'] = ' CPF = No  '
   if self.Vemail.get() == 1:
      v[3] = 1
      self.emailMarcado['text'] = ' Email = Sim  '
   else:
      self.emailMarcado['text'] = ' Email = No'

  def enviaBanco(self):
   if self.E2.get() == self.E3.get():
    self.frame0.pack_forget()
    self.frame1.pack_forget()
    self.frame2.pack_forget()
    self.frame5.pack_forget()
    self.nomeMarcado.pack_forget()
    self.corMarcado.pack_forget()
    self.cpfMarcado.pack_forget()
    self.emailMarcado.pack_forget()
    self.frameBotEnviar.pack_forget() 
    self.BotEnviar.pack_forget()
    self.L1.pack_forget()
    self.LL1.pack_forget()
    self.L2.pack_forget()
    self.L3.pack_forget()
    self.E1.pack_forget()
    self.E2.pack_forget()
    self.E3.pack_forget()
    self.nome.pack_forget()
    self.cor.pack_forget()
    self.cpf.pack_forget()
    self.email.pack_forget()
    inicioBanco(principal) 
 else:
    self.E2.delete(0, END) 
    self.E3.delete(0, END)

###############
```

Assim que voce colocar o nome e a senha e confirmar a senha e apertar enviar ele vai para esse arquivo com nome de Criacao.py

```
from Tkinter import *

class inicioBanco(object):
 def __init__(self, principal):
  self.frame11 = Frame(principal)
  self.frame11.pack()
  self.frame22 = Frame(principal)
  self.frame22.pack()
  usuarios = Label(self.frame11, text = 'Quantas Pessoas Voce Quer Cadastrar ?')
  usuarios.pack()
  self.entUsuarios = Entry(self.frame11, bd = 5, highlightcolor = '#1E90FF')
  entUsuarios.pack()
  Benviar = Button(self.frame22, text = 'Enviar', bd = 5)
  Benviar.pack()
```

ai quando vai para o arquivo acima, da o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/giovanni/Área de Trabalho/Python/BD.py", line 122, in 
enviaBanco
    inicioBanco(principal)
NameError: global name 'principal' is not defined
```

Eu sei que é porque o nome principla não esta definido mas eu não consigo defini-lo pois principal é a instancia de Tk() então se eu colocar:

```
principal = Tk()
principal.geometry('800x600')
principal.resizable(False, False)
principal.title('Gerenciador De Cadastro')
principal.mainloop()
```

Ira ficar abrindo varias janela. Então Se entenderem me ajudem preciso muito. Lembrando **CADA BLOCO É UM ARQUIVO COM NOME DIFERENTER O PRIMEIRO BOLBO É Gerenciador.py O SEGUNDO É BD.py E O TERCEIRO Criacao.py**

Answer (score 1):

Na definição `init` da função `main` (Em python, defina nomes de classes em camel-case, sugiro que de uma lida na [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))  `def __init__(self, principal):` você envia o parâmetro "principal" de algum lugar certo?

```
class main():
  def __init__(self, principal):

    self.frame1 = Frame(principal)
    self.frame1.pack()
    ...
```

Ai, mais abaixo, na mesma classe você define a função criar:

```
 def criar(self):

   self.BCriar.pack_forget()
   self.BGerenciar.pack_forget()
   self.BDeletar.pack_forget()
   self.BAjuda.pack_forget()
   self.BSobre.pack_forget()
   criarBanco()
   .....
```

A classe criar banco tem a função init com a seguinte assinatura:

```
class criarBanco(object):
  def __init__(self, principal):
  .....
```

Ok, mas quando você chama `criarBanco` (Novamente sugiro que de uma olha no guia de formatação de codificação [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), seria mais "pythonico" se o nome dessa classe fosse `CriarBanco`) você não envia o parâmetro principal, então como essa função vai conhecer esse parâmetro?

Você pode corrigir isso de duas maneiras: 
Tornando global a variável principal no escopo do pacote onde ela foi criada e importa-la em cada pacote que precisar ou envia-la "de mão em mão" a cada chamada de função que for utiliza-la.

Você pode fazer o seguinte teste: Logo na primeira linha de cada função que vc precisar da variável "principal", faça um print assim:

```
print (principal==None)
```

E verifique o resultado.

Comment: Como assim tornar a variável principal no escopo ? e envia-la de mão em mão ?

Comment: Ficou aparecendo false, mas ainda nao conseguir resolver

Comment: É como se o programa não conseguisse passar para a outra janela de Criação

Comment: Quando eu importo ela o programa abre duas janelas a primeira da um erro e a segunda continua como se nada tivesse mudado

Comment: Na verdade eu errei na digitacao, ja corrigi, o que eu quis dizer é "tornar global a variavel principal" no escopo onde ela é criada ou envia-la como parametro a cada vez que chamar alguma funcao q precise dela.

Comment: Voce poderia me ajudar com isso pq não consigo de jeito nenhum